# When was the first shadow crocodile created?

Tags: kagewani

In episode 12 of *Kagewani*, Banba and Kimura both state that disappearances that are recorded as having happened in Yunnan (in modern-day China) are in fact the handiwork of the shadow crocodile, and that one of the warring factions in that region created the first shadow crocodile by the method of [*gu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gu_(poison)).

I don't recall them ever mentioning Yunnan before or after that, but the way they state it so matter-of-factly makes me feel like I'm missing out on something. When did these disappearances happen? Is there an allusion to real-world history I'm not getting here?